# how to save last id inside class?

Tags: php, pdo, lastinsertid

there is a way to save the $id inside the class so I can use it next time I run the function?

so far I get the right $id inside the function after the query is executed, but when I re-run the function I get an uninitialised $id again.

```
class ShortURL {
    public $id;
    public $val2;

    function insert() {

        $conn = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USER, DB_PASS );
        $sql = "INSERT INTO art ( val1, val2 ) VALUES ( :val1, :val2 )";
        $st = $conn->prepare( $sql );
        $st->bindValue( ":val1", self::hash ( $this->id+1 ), PDO::PARAM_STR );
        $st->bindValue( ":val2", $this->val2, PDO::PARAM_STR );     
        $st->execute();
        $this->id = $conn->lastInsertId();
        $conn = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you create a new object of the class before calling `insert()`? Either do not do that or use static attributes.

Comment: note that keeping track of the id will only be useful if you're just inserting to this one table. lastInsertId() isn't table specific.

Comment: yes, I create a new object of the class first. I'll try with static to see if it works.
I was thinking as last resort to get the id from database and use it :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create a new instance of the class before you execute your function then the variable will get reset. So when you do the following:

```
$insert = new ShortURL();
$insert->insert();
echo $insert->id;
//You should see your value correctly
$insert = new ShortURL();
echo $insert->id;
//Now that you initialized the function again, the value is cleared
```

Try creating your class then reusing the same instance of the class.

Comment: ahh.. you are so right. Since I can't reuse the same instance of the class, I guess my best options are to update the database using the right id right away, or save the $id value in a session. I guess the session idea is better.